# updating object state from another class

Tags: php

Hello all i'm a noob here and to oophp.

I'm looking to update an exiting objects state from another class.

So in the main file i have...

```
$obj1 = new class1();
$obj2 = new class2();
```

and in class1 i have i setter method that changes the objects state.

soooo what i'm looking at doing, from within an existing method of class2 is something like this...

```
$obj1->updateName('Bob');
```

Static Methods are no good as i have to relate to the same objects state later.

here's a one page example....

```
class class1(){

    private $name = '';

    public function updateName($nameIn){
        $this->name = $nameIn;
    }

}

class class2(){

    public function someFuntion(){

        //OTHER CODE//

        $obj1->updateName('Bob');
    }
}


$obj1 = new class1();
$obj2 = new class2();

$obj2->someFuntion();
```

Hope this makes some sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to pass `$obj1` as a reference to `class2::someFunction()`:

```
class class2(){

    public function someFunction(&$obj1){

        //OTHER CODE//

        $obj1->updateName('Bob');
    }
}

$obj1 = new class1();
$obj2 = new class2();

$obj2->someFunction($obj1);
```

Note that the instruction to pass by reference is part of the `someFunction` definition by prepending the parameter with `&`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 0):

You could always pass `$obj1` as a parameter to someFunction.

```
class class1(){
    private $name = '';

    public function updateName($nameIn){
        $this->name = $nameIn;
    }
}

class class2(){
    public function someMethod(class1 $class){
        $class->updateName('Bob');
    }
}


$obj1 = new class1();
$obj2 = new class2();

$obj2->someMethod($obj1);
```